# zsh bad interpreter error for shebang in python file

Tags: python, zsh, shebang

I have a python code which works perfectly and i want to make it more user friendly to run, so i copied the code in a new file called codee.command , wrote `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` at the beginning and used `chmod 770 codee.command`.
Then i tried double clicking on the file but it returned the following error:

```
/Users/serax/Desktop/Code/digits_exec.command ; exit;
zsh: /Users/serax/Desktop/Code/digits_exec.command: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python3^M: no such file or directory
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed
```

I have worked on this code on vscode and I used python 3.9.6 which is installed in `/usr/local/bin/`.
I also tried with `#!/usr/bin/python3` (which contains python 3.8.2, that is not the interpreter i want) but it gives the same error.

I now tried with `#!/usr/local/bin python3` and it says `permission denied`.

Apparently my question is a duplicate of

[Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: That should be `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` with a slash, not a space.

Comment: Duplicate of [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: @serax : The error message says it pretty clear: Your #! has a carriage return character at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a line ending problem. There's a carriage return `^M` in `digits_exec.command` it seems. Remove it in a suitable editor or run dos2unix on the file.